# Free code camp Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Pig Latin Regex solution

Tags: regex

I found this really elegant solution for the pig latin converter but i cant seem to figure it out the regex to it. The  "$&way" or the  "$2$1ay" on the replace. Could someone explain this please?

```
  function translatePigLatin(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/^[aeiou]\w*/, "$&way")
    .replace(/(^[^aeiou]+)(\w*)/, "$2$1ay");
}

// test here
translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Comment: can't understand what's the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be "Solution 4" from "[freeCodeCamp Challenge Guide: Pig Latin](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/freecodecamp-challenge-guide-pig-latin/16039)". The page explains exactly what it does.

I guess the question is about the meaning of `$&`, `$2`, ...

- `$&` is the whole string that was matched by the regex
- `$1` is the part in the first pair of parentheses
- `$2` the second parentheses
- etc.

See for example here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: Im still so confused with this solution