# Using regex to get all consonants until a vowel appears

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I'm trying to create a higher order function that would do two things.

First: it would check the first letter of a string if it's a vowel, if it is, it would append at the end of the string 'way'.

I've done so with this code:

```js
const vowel = /[aeiou]/;
const consonant = /^[^aeiou]/gi;
const chaVow = 'way';
const chaCon = 'ay';

function pigLatinVowel(str) {
  if (!str.charAt(0) == vowel) {
    return str
  } else {
    return str.concat(chaVow)
  }
}

console.log(pigLatinVowel("algorithm"));
```

Then I need to code to run a specific task while checking for consonants instead. It has to check if the first letter (or group of letters) of a string is a consonant, push it to the end of the string and append the string 'ay'. I'm having problems with the regex, its not exactly what I'm looking for but I'm utterly lost. Here goes the code I'm using so far:

```js
const vowel = /[aeiou]/;
const consonant = /^[^aeiou]/gi;
const chaVow = 'way';
const chaCon = 'ay';

function pigLatinConsonant(str) {
  str = str.split('');
  let filtered = str.filter(a => a.match(consonant));
  return filtered;
}
console.log(pigLatinConsonant("glove"));
```

Ideally the regex would stop at the first vowel so it doesn't give me this output: `[ 'g', 'l', 'v' ]`

Obviously the function is not done yet and there is still some work to do. I don't want the whole answer as how would I go about creating the HoF and the rest, I'm learning through a course @FreeCodeCamp and I'm stubborn about it but I'm failing miserably at this step :(.

Perhaps I'm failing somewhere else but so far this function is driving me crazy.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused...there's two functions you're having trouble making the second function work...I think...what's wrong with the first function? What is your objective ? What is the expected behavior of the broken function? One or both or none of those functions work?

Comment: My goal is to create a higher order function with the two functions. The first function is fine, I was just placing people in context so they can see the whole picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

The second function should just check for the first letter of the string (or group of letters) if they are consonants, if they are, move them to the end of the original string and append the string 'ay' at the end of the string.

Comment: `vowel` is a RegExp, that does not equal a char.

Comment: But the charAt(0) checks if the character is part of a group of reGex which I have defined with the variable vowel. That part of the exercise works as intended to me.

Comment: It can't work as intended, a string can never be equal to a regexp. You need to write `vowel.test(str[0])` (there's also no need to use `charAt(0)`).

Comment: Well, I'm not going to discuss since I'm no expert, but your code throws this in the exercise console: str[0].test is not a function. Like I said, the code I'm using for what I need it just works ok. EDIT: just run the code, I've console.log the function call.

Comment: Have a look at [Free code camp Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Pig Latin Regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477264/free-code-camp-intermediate-algorithm-scripting-pig-latin-regex-solution). The question contains some code that is said to be a solution for piglatin string conversion.

Comment: Thats the exercise I'm doing lol, couldn't really see any hints just by looking at the question itself tho. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with a capturing group to get all the consonants before the first vowel in the string `/^([^aeiou]+)[aeiou]/i`. Then base your logic on the result of `match()`

```js
const atternpay = /^([^aeiou]+)[aeiou]/i;
const chaVow = 'way';
const chaCon = 'ay';

function pigLatinConsonant(str) {
  let con_prefix = str.match(atternpay);
  if (null === con_prefix)
    return str + chaVow;

  return str.substring(con_prefix[1].length) + con_prefix[1] + chaCon
}
console.log(pigLatinConsonant("glove"));
console.log(pigLatinConsonant("also"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches a sequence of consonants at the beginning of a string:

```
function startingConsonants(string) {
    let m = string.match(/^[^aeiou]+/);
    return m && m[0];
}
```